# Ocaml defining a type and returning it in a function

Tags: ocaml

Lets say I have the following:

```
type person = string * int * int list

let create_person name age grades = 
      let new_person = person (name, age, grades)
;;
```

See the thing is, I'm trying to create a person, add the fields, and return it in this function. But I'm not sure how to actually use the type that I defined above.

Answer (score 1):

`person` is basically just another name for `string * int * int list`, so you don't have to write anything special when defining the tuple. Your function should just be:

```
let create_person name age grades = (name, age, grades);;
```

Note that you also don't need the extra `let`: you just want to return the tuple directly.

Comment: ahh ok thanks I didn't know that. Man ocaml is hard.

Comment: As you build up larger tuples, it's best to switch to records as you can label the elements for clarity. In this case, it makes a lot of sense to use records.